# Scaning BLE device by CBUUID doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to scan for a specific BLE Device on my app by specifying a CBUUID in the `scanForPeripheralsWithServices()`, but if I mention it scan is never processed.

Here is my `CBCentralManagerDelegate` code:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        print("BLE powered off")
        self.clearDevices()

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        // Indicate to user that the iOS device does not support BLE.
        print("BLE not supported")
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
        // Wait for another event
        print("BLE unknown event")
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        print("BLE powered on")
            self.startScanning()
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
        print("BLE reset")
        self.clearDevices()

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
        print("BLE unsupported event")
        break
    }
}


    func startScanning() {
    print("\(NSDate()) Start scanning...")
       if let central = centralManager {
        let dictionaryOfOptions = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true]
        let ble = [CBUUID(string: "B737D0FF-AF53-9B83-E5D2-922140A9FFFF")]
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(ble, options: nil)
        }
}



  func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Discovered peripheral \(RSSI) dBM name: \(peripheral.name)")
    print("UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)")
    print("Peripheral \(peripheral.identifier)")
    .....send event to server....   
    sleep(delayPolling)
    self.startScanning()

}
```

If I change the `scanForPeripheralsWithServices()` without any CBUUID String it works fine:

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: dictionaryOfOptions)
```

My main concern if to be able to launch this Thread in background and from Apple documentation, we need to scan for a specific device by specifying the CBUUID to be able to run my task.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that this UUID is the service that your device is advertising?  A BLE peripheral can have multiple services but only advertise a subset of them. When you discover the peripheral by scanning for `nil` what is in the advertisement data dictionary?

Comment: This uuid is given by the command peripheral.identifier.UUIDString

Comment: That is the peripheral's identifier, not the service identifier. You need to scan for the identifier of the service that the peripheral is advertising. You could have multiple peripherals advertising service "X", each would have its own unique identifier, so you scan for "X" not the peripheral identifier

Comment: Ok I see, I need to connect to the device to get its service list?

Comment: my problem is related to the type of BLE Device I'm trying to connect to....this is a simple Beacon object, and even if I'm trying to connect through a 3rd party app (such as BLE Scanner) I'm not able to retrieve any service. I through the UUID/identifier was sufficient...

Comment: An iBeacon doesn't advertise a service, you use a CLBeaconRegion in core location to detect it (actually most beacons do advertise a service to allow configuration but this is specific to each beacon manufacturer and the beacon typically only does this for a short period of time after it boots for security)